# Pymongo case insensitive regex query over a list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list that I would like to query against using `$in` in pymongo, but I also need it to be case insensitive for each value in the list. Before I needed the list, my code looked something like this:

```
query = {'field': {'$regex': 'value', '$options': 'i'}}
for i in col.find(query): print(i)
```

where col is the pymongo collection.

I tried doing this:

```
query = {'field': {'$regex': {'$in':['value1', 'value2']}, '$options': 'i'}}
for i in col.find(query): print(i)
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please add some sample documents and your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put pipe operator between regex . Try below query. Although I couldn't run this query as there are no sample documents.

```js
query = {'field': {'$regex': 'value1|value2'}, '$options': 'i'}}
```